# SwiftUI: how to navigate to a view from a wheel picker?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

How can I display a view when the user selects a type in the wheel picker in SwiftUI?

Comment: You want the view to change as the user spins the picker? Is this a child view in the same view controller, or are you presenting another view controller?

Comment: Yes. It's a child view in the same view controller!